# What's the best way to use Azure to stream videos in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have been working on a website to stream videos and I understand Microsoft recommends using Windows Azure. Does this replace Silverlight Streaming? Should the files be stored in the SQL Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the best way would be to store the video in BLOB storage on Azure Storage Services (note that this is different from SQLAzure).  It is cheaper to host than SQLAzure and you don't have to create any infrastructure to display them as they are URL accessible.  If you need to control access to the video, you'll want to look into Shared Access Signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I would also look into CDN, that is also a part of Microsoft's cloud platform.